# How to INSERT multiple values based on multiple subselects

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, bulkinsert

we have gone through a lot of threads, but cannot seem to understand how exactly to implement this in our case.

We want to have multiple INSERTed values with 1 script. The values are depending on multiple criteria of other tables. The best we have gotten is the following:

```
insert into
atransportordercustomfieldv (ID,CFBOOLEAN2)
SELECT ((select transord.nr from transord
left join consignment on consignment.ASENDUNGID = transord.sendungid
left join order on consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
left join atransportordercustomfieldv af on transord.nr = af.id
where order.frachtagnr = 2418850 and transord.nr not in (select id from atransportordercustomfieldv WHERE ID not in (select transord.nr from transord
left join consignment on transord.ASENDUNGID = consignment .sendungid
left join order on consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
left join atransportordercustomfieldv af on transord.nr = af.id
where order.frachtagnr = 2418850))),0)
```

This does not work, but it can provide information about what we are trying to filter as it is a bit complex.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example: what do you currently have and what is required.

Comment: Is the `transord.asendungid = consignment.sendungid` join clause correct in the `not exists` subquery? In your main query, it's `consignment.asendungid = transord.sendungid` - i.e. the aliases are switched over.

Answer (score 1):

you would add the second column to the first select

```
insert into
atransportordercustomfieldv (ID,CFBOOLEAN2)
select transord.nr,0 
from transord
left join consignment on consignment.ASENDUNGID = transord.sendungid
left join order on consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
left join atransportordercustomfieldv af on transord.nr = af.id
where order.frachtagnr = 2418850 and transord.nr not in (select id from atransportordercustomfieldv WHERE ID not in (select transord.nr from transord
left join consignment on transord.ASENDUNGID = consignment .sendungid
left join order on consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
left join atransportordercustomfieldv af on transord.nr = af.id
where order.frachtagnr = 2418850)
```

Comment: It gives "Single row subquery returns more than one row" error.

Comment: this error can't happen with that query basically we make https://dbfiddle.uk/XyBfCG3Q if you change the fiddle to demonstrate your problem, we can take a look at it

Comment: We found a roundabout way and managed to make the whole thing work. Thank you for the time.

Comment: Ok if you have a solution post it as answer add information why it works and accept it, I am interested too

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can insert rows into a table using an `insert` statement:

- `insert into <table_name> (<column_list>) values (<corresponding list of values>);` - to insert a single row
- `insert into <table_name> (<column_list>) select <corresponding list of columns from <table(s)/subqueries/etc>;` - to insert however many rows are returned by the select statement (0 to many)

The example statement you provided in your question has somehow merged these two methods into a single (invalid) insert statement.

Since you have multiple rows to insert, and a select statement that generates those rows, you want to use the second method (as per @nbk's answer):

```
INSERT INTO atransportordercustomfieldv (id, cfboolean2)
SELECT transord.nr,
       0
FROM   transord
LEFT   JOIN consignment
ON     consignment.asendungid = transord.sendungid
LEFT   JOIN ORDER ON consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
LEFT   JOIN atransportordercustomfieldv af
ON     transord.nr = af.id
WHERE  order.frachtagnr = 2418850
AND    transord.nr NOT IN (SELECT id
                           FROM   atransportordercustomfieldv
                           WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT transord.nr
                                             FROM   transord
                                             LEFT   JOIN consignment
                                             ON     transord.asendungid = consignment.sendungid
                                             LEFT   JOIN ORDER ON consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
                                             LEFT   JOIN atransportordercustomfieldv af
                                             ON     transord.nr = af.id
                                             WHERE  order.frachtagnr = 2418850));
```

Depending on whether the logic in your subquery is correct, it may be that you could do the same thing in an insert-only `merge` statement, but looking at your query, it seems that maybe that won't be possible.

However, if your requirement is to insert ids from the `transord` table and its joins (which, btw, you don't need all of - you aren't using anything from the `atransportordercustomfieldv` table/view) that aren't already present in the atransportordercustomfieldv table/view, maybe something like the following would do the trick:

```
MERGE INTO atransportordercustomfieldv tgt
USING (SELECT transord.nr
       FROM   transord
       LEFT   JOIN consignment
       ON     consignment.asendungid = transord.sendungid
       LEFT   JOIN ORDER ON consignment.akopfnr = order.nr
       WHERE  order.frachtagnr = 2418850) src
  ON (tgt.id = src.nr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (tgt.id, tgt.cfboolean2)
  VALUES (src.nr, 0);
```